# Finding index of vector from two other vectors

Tags: r, match

I am trying to index a vector using two other vectors. I can index from the first vector with no issue, but my conditional index from the second value has been causing issues.

My example code is as follows

```
h=rep(seq(1:24),90)
m=rep(1:3,each=24*30)
d=rep(1:30,each=24*3)
```

My goal is to use match (or some other function if better suited) to determine which hour values correspond to all of the instances in which m=1 or m=2 and d=2 or 3

My attempt is as follows

```
hin=match(m,1)|(match(m,2)&match(d,2:3))
```

In this case elements 1:720, and 745:793 should result in True however only 1:720 are TRUE. How do I execute the second portion of the above argument so the later values are identified?

**EDIT**

To create a more reproducible example:

```
h2=rep(seq(1:5),4)
d2=rep(rep(1:2,each=5),2)
m2=rep(1:2,each=10)
```

Goal is to create a logical vector containing 10 TRUE, 5 FALSE, 5 TRUE
(m=1 or (m=2 and d=2))
Eventually using this logical vector will create a new h2 removing elements 11:15

Goal outputs:

```
hin2=c(rep("TRUE",10),rep("FALSE",5),rep("TRUE",5))
h2new=c(rep(seq(1:5),2),rep(NA,5),seq(1:5))

hin2
 [1] "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "FALSE"
[12] "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE" 

h2new
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using literally logical operators gives the boolean `hin2`. Then just `replace` the negation with `NA`.

```
hin2 <- m2 %in% 1 | (m2 %in% 2 & d2 %in% 2)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
h2new <- replace(h2, !hin2, NA)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

To select the values, do:

```
h_new <- h2[!is.na(h2new)]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `h2` values which satisfy the condition with `NA` :

```
h2[!((m2 == 1) | (m2 == 2 & d2 == 2))] <- NA
h2
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: Not quite. My goal is to determine the index location of all points in which m=1 or m=2 and d=2 or 3. Ideally, I would be able to use the resulting vector to subset the data from the equivalent indexes in a different data.frame

Comment: To further clarify, I was imagining that I would have a vector the same length as the above m and d vectors but would contain only the data matching the data where m=1 or (m=2 and d=2 or 3), with the rest be NaN values.

Comment: @johnnyg Can you create a small example and show expected output for it? Currently, length of `m`, `h` and `d` is 2160 which makes it difficult to test what you want exactly.

Comment: I think my answer already gives `index location of all points in which m=1 or m=2 and d=2 or 3.`. This is what this code returns `which(m %in% 1:2 & d %in% 2:3)`

Comment: @Gwang-Jin Kim There are no `d2 == 3` value in `d2`. Also I think OP changed their condition in the edit. Now the condition is `(m=1 or (m=2 and d=2))`

Comment: @RonakShah but in the first and second comment here he says d = 2 or 3

Comment: The comment was from before edit. Before edit the condition was `m=1 or m=2 and d=2 or 3`, after edit it changed to `(m=1 or (m=2 and d=2))`. I am trying to answer the question which was asked after the edit.